# Split row into multiple rows Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 5 columns: ID, ERROR1, ERROR2, ERROR3, ERROR4.

A small sample would look like:

```
ID | Error 1 | Error 2 | Error 3 | Error 4 |
12 | YES     | (null)  |  (null) | YES |
15 |  (null) | YES     |  (null) | YES |
```

So, I need to understand how to break a single row of data where there are multiple columns with "Yes" and turn it into multiple instances of the same ID, and only a single column reading Yes for that instance. So two records of 12 and two records of 15, each having only one error and the rest Null for any individual row.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that help, but I'm not sure, if I understand your expected result correctly:

```
 SELECT ID, Error1, NULL AS Error2, NULL AS Error3, NULL AS Error4
   FROM table
  WHERE Error1 = 'YES'
  UNION
    ALL
 SELECT ID, NULL AS Error1, Error2, NULL AS Error3, NULL AS Error4
   FROM table
  WHERE Error2 = 'YES'
  UNION
    ALL
 SELECT ID, NULL AS Error1, NULL AS Error2, Error3, NULL AS Error4
   FROM table
  WHERE Error3 = 'YES'
   UNION
    ALL
 SELECT ID, NULL AS Error1, NULL AS Error2, NULL AS Error3, Error4
   FROM table
  WHERE Error4 = 'YES'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you could join your table on a "[diagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix)", taking benefice in the join clause that  `NULL` is not equal to `NULL`:

```
SELECT T.ID, O.*
FROM T JOIN (
 --
 -- build a diagonal matrix
 --
 SELECT 'YES' as "Error 1", NULL as "Error 2", NULL as "Error 3", NULL as "Error 4"
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL SELECT NULL, 'YES', NULL, NULL
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, 'YES', NULL
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, 'YES'
  FROM DUAL
) O
ON T."Error 1" = O."Error 1"
OR T."Error 2" = O."Error 2"
OR T."Error 3" = O."Error 3"
OR T."Error 4" = O."Error 4";
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc0a7f/12

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the output for the following query

```
SELECT ID,
DECODE(COL_NUM,
    1, "ERROR 1",
    2, "ERROR 2",
    3, "ERROR 3",
    "ERROR 4") AS ERROR_COL
DECODE(COL_NUM,
        1, ERROR1,
        2, ERROR2,
        3, ERROR3,
        ERROR4) AS ERROR
FROM
TABLE,
(SELECT ROWNUM AS COL_NUM FROM DUAL WHERE ROWNUM<5)
WHERE
DECODE(COL_NUM,
        1, ERROR1,
        2, ERROR2,
        3, ERROR3,
        ERROR4) IS NOT NULL
```

ID----ERROR_COL----ERROR

12----ERROR 1------YES

12----ERROR 4------YES

15----ERROR 2------YES

15----ERROR 4------YES